# Pass headers while redirecting the url through chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to pass the headers as well as the body while redirecting the URL from chrome extension.

```
  function (details) {

    if (details.type == "xmlhttprequest") {
      let index = details.url.indexOf(".com");
      let redirect = "http://localhost:9010" + details.url.substring(index + 4)
      chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(redirect);
      return { redirectUrl: redirect };
    }

  }, { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

Comment: As you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-BlockingResponse) returning both `redirectUrl` and headers is possible only in one event: onHeadersReceived. In all other cases you need to use an additional event listener to change the headers.